# Google Maps API V3 - How to change origin and destination points for Direction Service

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have no trouble initially setting an origin and a destination with direct services through Google Maps API.  (my code is below). But how can we dynamically change these values after the page loads so that my web site visitors can continue to input various from/to points they type into my form fields...?

```
function directions(map) {
/*EXTENDED GOOGLE MAP DIRECTIONS*/

var from = '12345 New York, NY'; 
var to =  '12345 Indianapolis, IN';

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));

var directionsRequest = {
  origin: from,
  destination: to,
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
};

directionsService.route(
  directionsRequest,
  function(response, status)
  {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
    {


      new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map: map,
        directions: response
      });
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
    else
      $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your route<br />");
  }
);
/**/
}

function initialize() {
/*GOOGLE MAP API V3*/
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);  

var mapOptions = {
zoom            : 17,
center          : new google.maps.LatLng(39.868041, -86.145084),
mapTypeId       : google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
backgroundColor : '#333'
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: mapOptions.center,
map: map,
title: 'My Location'
});

//my extended directions for my map
directions(map);

setTimeout(function(){$('base').prevAll().remove();}, 1000);
/**/
}

function loadScript() {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' + 'callback=initialize';
document.body.appendChild(script);
}

$(window).load(function(){
loadScript();
});
```

Comment: Refactor your code.  Only initialize the map (and load the API) on page load, put the directions calls into a function that you call when you want a new set of directions to be submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Google Maps setup allows me to load my map initially with a starting point marker.  Then if a web user decides to submit an origin point, that data gets sent to directionService to be calculated and finally displayed. I am also loading driving steps into a panel as well.  I hope this is a help for someone who is in need of setting and recalculating origin and destination points:

Call Google Maps with your API key

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>
```

Then use the following...

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
/*INITIALIZE GOOGLE MAPS V3*/
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var npcc = new google.maps.LatLng(39.868041, -86.145084);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom             : 17,
    center         : npcc,
    mapTypeId      : google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    backgroundColor:'#333'
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);  

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: mapOptions.center,
    map: map,
    title: 'My initial starting point'
    });

    //remove all unnecessary styles from Google Maps v3
    setTimeout(function(){$('base').prevAll().remove();}, 1000);
/**/
}


function calcRoute() {
/*CALCULATE AND DISPLAY ROUTE DATA*/
    var from = $('#from').val();
    var to = '6202 N Carrollton Ave, Indianapolis';
    var directionsRequest = {
        origin: from,
        destination: to,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
    };

  directionsService.route(directionsRequest, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
    else {
    console.log("Unable to retrieve your route<br />");
      }
  });
/**/
}

function getRoute() {
/*ON HTML FORM SUBMIT, PROCESS ROUTE DATA*/
  $('#coming-from').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  calcRoute();
  });
 /**/   
 }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(window).load(function(){ 
  getRoute();
});
```